# Creating Array of weapons for Math.Random to choose from

Tags: java, arrays, class, random, interface

I am just a little bit confused as of what to do.  I have Two Weapons Classes.  One for  the M16 and another for the M4.  I then have those Classes implementing an interface named Armory.  But I am having issues with the Combat class.  In the combat class I have a Random number Generator that will generate a random number and depending on what number it is, will either give the player a weapon or do nothing.  I will post the Code Below:

Interface:

```
public interface Armory {

public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo);
public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage);
public String weaponName(String wepName);   
}
```

M4 Class(M4 and M16 Classes are the same except for damage and ammo amounts):

```
public class M4 implements Armory {

public Integer weaponAmmo(int wepAmmo) {
    wepAmmo = 10;
    return wepAmmo;
}

public Integer weaponDamage(int wepDamage) {
    wepDamage = 2;
    return wepDamage;
}

public String weaponName(String wepName) {
    wepName = "M4";
    return wepName;
}
```

And Finally, the Combat Class(This is where I am having Issues):

```
public class Combat {
final int chanceOfDrop = 3;

Weapons[] wepArray = {new M4(), new M16()};  //Issues here.. Don't really know how to implement this.

static boolean[] hasWeapon = {false, true};



public static int  ranNumberGen(int chanceOfDrop) {
    return (int) (Math.random()*1); 
}

private void enemyDead() {
    boolean canDrop = false;
    if(ranNumberGen(chanceOfDrop)==0){
        canDrop = true;

    }

    if(canDrop == true){
        givePlayerWeapon(wepArray[Combat.ranNumberGen(wepArray.length)] } //Issues here also.
    private static void givePlayerWeapon(int w) {
        hasWeapon[w] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < hasWeapon.length; ++i)
        {
            if (hasWeapon[i]) System.out.println(( wepArray[i]).weaponName());  //And, last but not least, I am having Issues here
        }
            }



}
```

NOTE: I have a Weapons Class, But nothing is in it.  I don't really know what to put in it.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance:
Shandan

Comment: Your post contains `M4` twice

Comment: @ShandanSpencer: What are your issues? I'm not getting it clear in my mind

Comment: @codeMaker  On the wepArray, I am getting an error saying that I cannot convert from M4 to Weapons or from M16 to Weapons.  The givePlayerWeapons method says it is not applicable for arguments. That's about it.

Comment: @ShandanSpencer: it would be better to analyse if you could put Weapons class

Comment: You're creating an array of `Weapons`, but its element are not instances of `Weapons`. That's like wanting to put bananas into an egg box. It doesn't work. An egg box is for eggs.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues - 
A. To put m16 and m14 elements in the weapons array , these classes must either extend (if Weapons is a class) or implmeent (if weapons is interface) Weapons. 
 
Another option is to have a method of 
`Weapons toWeapons()` in both M16 and M14 classes. 
B. Correct me if I'm wrong (Not native english speaker - but Armory is a place that provides Weapons, so your choice of name is not good. 
M16 and M14 should implement an interface named "Weapon" and this (In my humble opinion) should be the type of the array. 
C. If I understood, you want to provide in some cases no weapon to the user - 
One way to have this done, and not get into ugly if (to check existence or not) is to have a NoWeapon class implements Weapon (in your current code - implements Armory). 
Its methods will have an applicative meaning of "do nothing". 
For example -
weaponAmmo will always return 0.